# determine the isolated singularities and the associated residues for the following function $\frac{1}{1+z^{2}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have to determine the isolated singularities and the associated residues for the following function

$\frac{1}{1+z^{2}}$

I believe that the isolated singularity here would have to be z = i, since 1 + i ^ 2 = 1-1 = 0 and thus the function would not be defined. however, I don't know how to determine the residue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{1+z^2}$$

has two simple poles $z_k$ for $k = 0, 1$, at $z_k = e^{(i(2k+1)\pi)/2}$

The residue is the coefficient $a_{-1}$ of the Laurent Series of the function around $z_0$. Or, in a simpler way,

$$\text{Res}\left(f(z); z_k\right) = \frac{1}{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}z}(z^2+1)_{z_k}} = \frac{1}{2z_k} = \frac{1}{2 e^{(i(2k+1)\pi)/2}} = \begin{cases} -\frac{i}{2} ~~~& k = 0 \\  \frac{i}{2} ~~~& k = 1 \end{cases}$$

because when $f$ is of the form $f(z)=\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}$, where both numerator and
denominator are analytical functions, the following equality holds

\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{Res}\left( f(z);z_{k}\right) =\frac{p(z_{k})}{q^{\prime }(z_k)}
\end{equation*}
provided that $z_{k}$ is a simple pole of $f(z)$ and $p(z_{k})\neq 0$, $
q(z_{k})=0$, $q'(z_{k})\neq 0$.